# How to zoom in and center the user location (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

How do I zoom in and center the user location "dot"? I've tried everything I've found on here and on other sites, but I can't seem to get it right.

Please help me!

EDIT: I've tried to implement this line of code in viewDidAppear. I found it in an old thread somewhere, but it doesn't seem to work anymore...

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
```

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried. Explain what issue you are having with the code.

Comment: Have you verified that `mapView` isn't `nil`? Have you verified that `mapView.userLocation` isn't `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the map programmatically instead of using a MapKit View, and it works perfectly!

Here's the code:

```
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];

}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate Methods

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1f, 0.1))animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting region for the map, I am listing all steps just in case you missed anything, let me know which ones you are missing and I would provide the code.

In `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` whichever suits your flow. you have to initiate the map and hook for update positions once the map is initialized and listening for position updates in your `didUpdateUserLocation` you need to set the region like this

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    //Mapview is your map on display,      
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

    //Create a region with a 1000x1000 meter around the user location
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 1000, 1000);

    //Set the region of your mapview so the user location is in center and update
    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion];

}
```